# Python function translate relative path ../../ into full path

Tags: python, string, function, path

is there a function that translate relative path ../test.txt into a full path?
example:

the full path is:

```
/Users/paganotti/Documents/Project/simple/work/paga/
```

the relative path is:

```
../test.txt
```

I want build this result:

```
/Users/paganotti/Documents/Project/simple/work/test.txt
```

As you can see translate ../ into  "work" folder for build entire path.

Is there general function that acomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`normpath()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) from the `os.path` module to get a normalize path from one with `".."` and similar constructs:

```
base = '/Users/paganotti/Documents/Project/simple/work/paga/'
rel = '../test.txt'

print os.path.normpath(os.path.join(base, rel))
```

Answer (score 16):

use this:

```
import os
os.path.abspath('../test.txt')
```

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)